# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un procedimiento almacenado que me permita elegir qué tabla afectar?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Me pidieron crear un procedimiento almacenado mediante el cual poder seleccionar en qué tabla quiero actualizar el registro. Ejemplo: tengo 2 tablas, *ciudad* y *festival*. Quiero poder elegir si quiero actualizar digamos el nombre de la ciudad desde el procedimiento alamcenado.

Adjunto el código que desarrollé y funciona, pero quiero saber si hay alguna manera de hacer mas fácil y de una manera que no sea escribiendo textual el nombre de la tabla.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_Actuliza`(IN `pNomTablas` VARCHAR(100), IN `pDetalle` VARCHAR(100), 
        IN `pIdDato` INT(11))
        BEGIN
        IF pNomTablas='banda' THEN
        UPDATE dbfestivales.banda SET NombreBanda=pDetalle WHERE IdBanda=pIdDato;
        ELSEIF pNomTablas='festival' THEN
        UPDATE dbfestivales.banda  SET NombreFestival=pDetalle WHERE IdFestival=pIdDato;
        END IF;
END
```

Comment: Puedes armar un string concatenando lo que necesites y luego ejecutarlo. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 0):

La forma más segura es construir dinámicamente la sentencia SQL, preparar con PREPARE un nuevo query y ejecutarlo con EXECUTE pasando los parámetros, algo parecido a esto

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN tabla VARCHAR(100), IN detalle VARCHAR(100), IN id INT)
  BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE ', tabla,
                 ' SET Nombre',@tabname, '=? WHERE id=?');
    PREPARE statement FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE statement USING detalle, id;
END;
```